# Paypal api checkout, custom field for each item

Tags: php, paypal

I am creating a simple webshop and for each item you add to your cart you need to specify a text. I know there is a field called on0 and os0 which let's you add a custom field label and custom field value. But I have a shopping cart in my webshop where all items are added together with each custom text field for each item.

So the problem I encounter is on the checkout page, where I need to build up the paypal form, which field name should I use for the custom field for each item?

In the checkout form I have this now for each item:

```
echo '<input name = "item_name_'.$i.'" value = "'.$_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$i]['item_name'].'" type = "hidden">';
echo '<input name = "quantity_'.$i.'" value = "1" type = "hidden">';
echo '<input name = "amount_'.$i.'" value = "'.$_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$i]['item_price'].'" type = "hidden">';
echo '<input name = "custom_'.$i.'" value = "'.$_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$i]['item_label'].'" type = "hidden">';
```

Where $i is the item number in the shopping cart.
The field 'custom_'.$i is not working, I wonder what I should use instead?

Comment: the variables are on0 through on6 and not `on0_somthing`

Comment: Ok thanks! I tested writing the following

    echo '<input name = "on0_'.$i.'" value = "Item label" type = "hidden">';
    echo '<input name = "os0_'.$i.'" value = "'.$_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$i]['item_label'].'" type = "hidden">';

and it worked!

Didn't find this in any documentation though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tested writing the following

```
echo '<input name = "on0_'.$i.'" value = "Item label" type = "hidden">';
echo '<input name = "os0_'.$i.'" value = "'.$_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$i]['item_label'].'" type = "hidden">';
```

and it worked!

Didn't find this in any documentation though.

Just remember to recieve the variables as:

```
$_POST['option_name1']
$_POST['option_selection1']
```